# regex expression to fetch last week data using perl

Tags: regex, perl, regex-group

I have a Perl script which will generate an output in one csv file. Perl script is giving an output based on monthly basis and executing on every Thursday. Please see the regular expression which i put into perl script.

```
'{"Date":{"\$regex":/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-10-2017/i}}'
```

But once the this output generates, i need to copy last week data(i.e. for e.g. 12th Oct to 18th) and needs to send to members. So i want regular expression in such way that it will send me an based on output last week.(Concurrent last week)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possible to generate a regex something like the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX qw/strftime/;

my $now = time;

my @dates;
push @dates, strftime "%d-%m-%Y", localtime($now - $_ * 86_400 ) for (0..6);

my $regex_string = '(' . join( '|', @dates) . ')';
```

Hope that will work for you

> I am aware of the problem one could potentially have with this, when
>   it's just after the moment Daylight Saving Time would start -- if
>   that is really a problem, then iterate over a `for` loop for 13 times,
>   with steps of 43.200 seconds, which is half a day decrements.